# jQuery : Select previous checkbox which is selected

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox, which upon a change in text, calls some Javascript.

Before this textbox, I have 2 checkboxes (chkA, chkB) which are mutually exclusive.
When I start my new function I want to be able to check which checkbox is currently selected. So far I have this,

```
   $(".textbox1").keyup(function () {
                var chk = $(this).prevAll(":checked").first().attr('class');  ....

    });
```

The code goes on to do a "If class = blah, then do something, else, do nothing"

it worked for my radio button code, but not my checkboxes. "chk" ends up being null.

Comment: .prevall() gives elements in **reverse** order (up through the list of previous siblings) so .first() is actually what you would otherwise expect to be last, and *vice versa*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to know the class of a checked checkbox (i used an imaginary element that i called "wrapper" which holds all your input fields, substitute that with the correct element or post your markup):

```
$(".textbox1").keyup(function () {
       if($(this).closest('#wrapper').find("input:checkbox:checked").hasClass('blah')){
          //do what you need

});
```

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea about the .closest() feature in JQ.

Answer (score 1):

"I have 2 checkboxes (chkA, chkB) which are mutually exclusive." The purpose of using checkboxes is to allow the user to make choices that are mutually **inclusive**. You may want to reconsider and use radio buttons (which are designed to be are mutually exclusive).

That said, your handler for `keyup` appears to be setting the class attribute of the closest (to the textbox) preceding element that has a checked attribute set to true. Do your checkboxes (chkA, chkB) meet that criteria, or are there other checkboxes after them (but before your textbox) that are checked?